# can not import google fonts on the server while it's working on the localhost

Tags: css, import, google-font-api

i'm using a carousel that has this code inside the css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
```

on my localhost when i remove this line the animation doesn't work and when i add this line the animation works which mean it's important to make the animation happen> the problem now is this code is not working on the server the animation doesn't work while the import line is already there.
Any ideas, please?

Comment: A font not loading shouldn't prevent an animation form working. You just wouldn't see the specified font. Is there anything in your js console?

Comment: yes : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for : http://www.fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700

Comment: worked after removing http://

Comment: That url has `www.` in it which is incorrect. That is different to the url in your question which works fine.